# import error fabric.api

Tags: python

I am trying to import `fabric.api` and having issues.
I installed fabric using pip and it works fin when I run `import fabric` in the interpreter.

But when I do `from fabric.api import *` it spews out an error saying "No module named api".
I am using Python 2.7. What am I missing here?

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'version' is not defined
>>> import fabric
>>> import fabric.api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named api
>>> from "fabric.api" import *
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from "fabric.api" import *
                    ^
```

Answer (score 13):

`Fabric` has made some major API changes from v1 to v2; to see the changes, visit [Upgrading from Fabric 1.x: API organization](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/upgrading.html#api-organization). In particular, `fabric.api` is removed and everything is imported directly from the top-level package. This means that your scripts won't work with the current `Fabric==2.0.1` version; you have two possibilities: rewrite your code to be compliant with v2, or install the latest v1 version:

```
$ pip install "fabric<2"
```

Answer (score 0):

`fabric.api` is part of version

> 1.14

you installed

> 2.4

please check versions

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling with the changes or have a long chain of tools based on fabric<2 but want to migrate to python 3 you can use

```
pip install fabric3
```

to get a working version that is python 3 compatible and uses fabric<2.